# resizing hta depending on screen resultion

Tags: javascript, html, screen-resolution, hta

I was wondering if there was a way to resize the window of an hta app with JavaScript when the screen resolution is too small for the app.

I know of:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        window.moveTo(60, 60);
        window.resizeTo(1400,850);
    </script>
```

but I just need to know how to grab the screen resolution and decipher it is too small for the hta.
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: window.screen.availHeight / availWidth is the available size

Comment: Alex K you should post this as an answer because you solved my problem =P